# Sql join select all values that not availible joined table

Tags: sql

is it posssible to select all rows from one table and some rows from other table using join,

here is the what i'm trying to do.

```
Select CT.COA_TypeId,CT.Code,CT.Types,SUM(GL.Amount) As Amount  
       from COA_Type CT 
       join ChartOfAccount CA on CT.COA_TypeId=CA.COA_Id 
       Join COA_Client CC on CA.COA_Id = CC.COA_Id 
       JOIN GeneralLedgerLine GL on CC.AccountId=GL.AccountId  
 Group BY CT.Code,CT.Types,CT.COA_TypeId
```

i want to select all CT.Types with amount, type rows that do not have Amount i want amount as null

[image]

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

```
Select CT.COA_TypeId,CT.Code,CT.Types,SUM(GL.Amount) As Amount  
       from COA_Type CT 
       INNER join ChartOfAccount CA on CT.COA_TypeId=CA.COA_Id 
       INNER Join COA_Client CC on CA.COA_Id = CC.COA_Id 
       LEFT JOIN GeneralLedgerLine GL on CC.AccountId=GL.AccountId  
 Group BY CT.Code,CT.Types,CT.COA_TypeId
```

By changing GeneralLedgerLine from an INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN, you will still get COA_Type records even though there isn't a matching GeneralLedgerLine.

NOTE: You might have to make the other joins into LEFT JOIN as well.